# Comparing one dataset with another dataset and updating both dataset

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataset Product and Delivery.

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Delivery_ID</th>
            <th>Count_Record</th> 
            <th>Order_Date</th>        
            <th>Product_Delivery_ID</th>
             <th>Qty_Delivered</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>      
            <td>30</td>
            <td>11/12/2016</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>20</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>2</td>      
            <td>40</td>
            <td>11/21/2016</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>0</td>       
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>3</td>      
            <td>20</td>
            <td>11/12/2013</td>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>0</td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
```

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Product_Delivery_ID</th>
            <th>Product_Name</th> 
            <th>Order_Date</th>        
            <th>Qty_Available</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>101</td>      
            <td>Product1</td>
            <td>12/11/2016</td>
            <td>10</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Product1</td> 
            <td>11/12/2016</td>
            <td>20</td>        
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Product2</td> 
            <td>12/13/2016</td>
            <td>2</td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
```

I would want to compare each and every record of Delivery dataset table with every other record of Product dataset.

Delivery dataset Count_Record column should be equalized by updating Qty_Delivered column based on the available quantity from Qty_Available column in Product dataset.

Updates should be done in both dataset. i.e Product dataset Qty_Available
should be subracted and Delivery dataset Qty_Delivered should be added. Final result should look like. Could someone let me know how this can be achieved.

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Product_Delivery_ID</th>
            <th>Product_Name</th> 
            <th>Order_Date</th>        
            <th>Qty_Available</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>101</td>      
            <td>Product1</td>
            <td>12/11/2016</td>
            <td>0</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Product1</td> 
            <td>11/12/2016</td>
            <td>0</td>        
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>Product2</td> 
            <td>12/13/2016</td>
            <td>0</td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
```

```html
<table>
          <tr>
            <th>Delivery_ID</th>
            <th>Count_Record</th> 
            <th>Order_Date</th>        
            <th>Product_Delivery_ID</th>
             <th>Qty_Delivered</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>      
            <td>30</td>
            <td>11/12/2016</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>30</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>2</td>      
            <td>40</td>
            <td>11/21/2016</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>20</td>       
          </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>3</td>      
            <td>20</td>
            <td>11/12/2013</td>
            <td>102</td>
            <td>2</td>        
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: How do you fetch that data ? I assume you want to perform some crud operations on server side, if so what was the point of that HTML code ?

Comment: These are transaction table data on day to day basis available on backend. HTML code is just the way I would want to present question, to make it clear...Please let me know how this operation can be achieved...I believe Joining tables is one of the approch. But not sure how to achieve the final output tables.